# QR barcode display based on textbox input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please I need assistance on the barcode display based on the textbox input. For instance if one type "Computer" and press "Enter" to enter another word. I want it to display on the barcode

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing QR code</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function generateBarCode()
            {
                var nric = $('#text').val();
                var url = 'https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=' + nric + '&amp;size=50x50';
                $('#barcode').attr('src', url);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="text" type="text" value="NRIC or Work Permit" style="Width:20%" onblur='generateBarCode();' /> <br>
        <br><br>
      <img id='barcode' 
            src="https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=HelloWorld&amp;size=100x100" 
            alt="" 
            title="HELLO" 
            width="100" 
            height="100" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `oninput` event to handle any changes in the text input:

```js
function generateBarCode() {
   var nric = $('#text').val();
   var url = 'https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=' + nric + '&amp;size=50x50';
   $('#barcode').attr('src', url);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <input id="text" type="text" value="NRIC or Work Permit" style="Width:20%" oninput='generateBarCode();' /> <br>
        <br><br>
      <img id='barcode' 
            src="https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=HelloWorld&amp;size=100x100" 
            alt="" 
            title="HELLO" 
            width="100" 
            height="100" />
```

Or you can detect when the user hit the enter key and update the barcode.

```js
 function generateBarCode(e) {
  var code = !e || (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  if(!e || code == 13) {
    var nric = $('#text').val();
    var url = 'https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=' + nric + '&amp;size=50x50';
    $('#barcode').attr('src', url);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="text" type="text" value="NRIC or Work Permit" style="Width:20%" onKeyPress='generateBarCode(event);' onblur='generateBarCode();' /> <br>
        <br><br>
      <img id='barcode' 
            src="https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=HelloWorld&amp;size=100x100" 
            alt="" 
            title="HELLO" 
            width="100" 
            height="100" />
```

In the above I used `var code = !e || (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);` to detect if enter was pressed `(e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which)` (For the keypress event), or if no key was pressed (`!e`) for the `onblur` event.

Comment: Thank you so much...but please I want the text input to go down when I press ENTER key. e.g. Add then If i press enter the new word should be under it

Comment: @ojulari Then you need to change your `input` into a `textarea`  which allows multiple lines